# How to use the definition of supremum to prove that $\sup{S} = 2$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $S$ $=$ {$2-\frac{3}{n+1} | n\in \mathbb{N}$}. Use the definition of supremum to prove that $\sup{S} = 2$.

Here's what I have so far. We want to show that $2$ is an upper bound, and it is also the least upper bound.

We know $2$ is an upper bound because, $2 - \frac{3}{n+1} < 2 \text{, for all } n \in \mathbb{N}$

But how do I show it's the least upper bound? Someone tried explaining it to me, and I still don't really understand.

Comment: Pick any $c < 2$ and show that $c$ is not an upper bound. Writing $c = 2-\varepsilon$ may help finding a proof.

Comment: Here is a useful characterization of a supremum: given any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $x \in S$ such that $\sup S - x < \varepsilon$. Does that help you?

Answer (score 5):

Assume that there is a LOWER bound, $2-\epsilon$, $\epsilon>0$. Then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$2-\frac{3}{n+1}<2-\epsilon$$
or
$$\epsilon<\frac{3}{n+1}$$ for ALL $n$. Can you take it from here?

Edit, let me do more algebra for you. This is equivalent to:

$$n<\frac{3}{\epsilon}-1$$

You're assuming this is true for ALL natural numbers. What's the problem?

Comment: Someone tried explaining it to me similar to this, but like I said, I still wasn't able to follow :( can you elaborate some more for me please?

Comment: I did some more algebra for you, it should be clear now.

Comment: So by that algebra, this tells us that $2-\epsilon$ can't be an upper bound? Which has to make $2$ the least upper bound?

Comment: Why though? Explain more.

Comment: Is it because that since it shows $2-\epsilon$ < $2 - \frac{3}{n+1}$, it contradicts our assumption that $2-\epsilon$ is an upper bound for the set?

Comment: You're just restating the conclusion. Why is the final statement a contradiction?

Comment: I'm not sure then :(

Comment: The final statement is: For all natural numbers $n$, $n<something$. Why is this not correct?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
Use method of contradiction :assume there is some number less than 2 which is supremum and contradict by showing a number in set can always be found greater than this assumed supremum.